# append a div to another div only once on droppable drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a draggable element , that when its dropped onto the target, it adds a delete button:

```
    $( "#committed" ).droppable({
                hoverClass: 'drophover',
                drop: function( event, ui )
                {

                    $(function()
                    {
                        var done;

                        if( done ) return;
                        done = true;

                        $(ui.draggable).append('<button class="delBtn" type="reset">X</button>');

                        $(ui.draggable).draggable( "option", "disabled", true );

                        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
                        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();                            

                    });

                }
```

Once its been dropped, it then becomes sortable. The issue is , everytime the element is sorted, the Delete button gets added again. As there are multiple elements being dragged and dropped and then sorted, so `.length>?` doesn't work.

I essentially need

```
If (this.delBtn exists)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated another jsfiddle project, there the button is added only if the button does not exist on the draggable object yet: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ghdekker/k68vj/3/)

The trick here is this:

```
if ($(ui.draggable).find('button.delBtn').length == 0) {
      $(ui.draggable).append('<button class="delBtn" type="reset">X</button>');
}
```

It checks if the dragged item contains a button with class delBtn. If not then it adds the button.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this sort you out?

```
if($('button.delBtn').length > 0)
{
    // The delete button exists...
}
```

Comment: But there can be multiple .delBtn elements, so this won't work after the first one is dropped.

Comment: But it answers the very last part of your question: 'If (This.delBtn exists)'?

Comment: Hmmm.. But unless I'm missing something, I need (THIS button.delBtn).length > 0 , not just the generic selector.

Comment: Then narrow the search to the ui.draggable element: `if (!$('button.delBtn', ui.draggable).length) // add button`